# display data in bootstrap card from web service call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm interested in dsiplaying data from web service call in the bootstrap card. Most of the example i see are using hard coded data, I have a simple UI to display web service data using `bootstrapTable` and bootstrap card.

```
<div class="card" id="card-data">
  <div class="front">
     <h1 id="front-label">{data.number}</h1>
     <p> 
        <span ><span class="card-front">Name :</span> {data.name}</span><br/>
        <span ><span class="card-front">Type :</span> {data.type} </span><br/>
        <span ><span class="card-front">Updated :</span> {data.date} </span><br/>
     <p>
   </div>
</div>
```

script logic

```
var data;
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/xxxxxx/getData", function(json){
       data = json;

        /*perhaps load data by id */
       .......

    });
});
```

I could have done this in angular or react by expressions on `$scope` or 'props` but we are not using any framework for this UI.

Comment: you makes this more difficult by nesting those spans. Throw some Identifiers on there and use jquery append or prepend. You realize how nice binding is in frameworks once you do it the long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the cleanest way but I was able to retrieve the JSON data and display it on the card.

```
<div class="card" id="card-data">
  <div class="front">
     <h1 id="data_number"></h1> 
   </div>
</div>
```

empty value will be replaced with value in `<h1 id="data_number"></h1>`

script

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var data = $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/xxxxxxx/getData", function(data) {
        $("#data_number").html(data[0].number);
    });
});
```